# val function in jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have those two line of code in my view

```
var selectProduct = $('#select-product');
var hasProduct = '@ViewBag.productName';
if (hasProduct != "") {
    alert(hasProduct);
    selectProduct.val(hasProduct);
    alert("Select Product = "+selectProduct.val());
 }
```

and this is the HTML of select-product

```
        <select id="select-product">
        <option>Select a Product</option>
        </select>
```

The first alert  -> alert(hasProduct) appear with the correct value coming from the viewbag but the second alert appear always with value = select a product.
Any help ?

Comment: What is select-product. Show some html

Comment: make sure your select has an option `@ViewBag.productName`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also think, you have to add the list of options before selecting the new entry. Try this (it worked in my browser):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selectProduct = $('#select-product');
    var hasProduct = 'New Product';
    alert(hasProduct);
    if (hasProduct != "") {
        alert(hasProduct);
        selectProduct.append("<option value='"+hasProduct+"'>"+hasProduct+"</option>");
        selectProduct.val(hasProduct);
        alert("Select Product = "+selectProduct.val());
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set value of an option which is already in your `select` tag. If you need to set new value, you need to append another option with the value.